# Mouse hover not working in only firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, hover, underline

I have tried and isolated the problem below after spending hours on this. First link is not underlined on hover in FF but works in all the other browsers I have tried. The second link properly works in Firefox too. Most of the existing html on the site is structured in the below way so a site wide fix will be appreciated.

**HTML:** <strike>(pasting as code here removes tags)</strike> http://pastebin.com/duqfKGeY

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>
FF test
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link href="ff.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
    <tr>
            <td>

        <ul type="disc">

                    <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://example1.com">
                <font size="2" color="#b80000"><b>Example Link 1</b></font></a>

                        <br>

            <font size="2" face="Verdana"> 

                example text  example text  example text  example text  example text  example text                  example text  example text  example text  example text  example text  example text                   example text  example text  example text  example text             example text 
                <a target="_blank" href="http://example2.com/">
                 <font size="2" face="Verdana" color="#b80000">Example link 2</font>
                </a>

                  example text  example text  example text  example text  example text  example text                    example text  example text  example text  example text  example text  example text  example text                example text  example text  example                 text  example text .
            </font> 
         </li>

        </ul>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
a{color:#b80000;}
a:link{color:#b80000;text-decoration:none;}
a:visited{color:#b80000;text-decoration:none;}
a:hover{color:#b80000;text-decoration:underline;}
a:active{color:#b80000;}
```

Edit: Validates without any errors on W3C Validator

Comment: (a) seems to work fine on FF 3.6.13 on Mac, and (b) `<font>` tag? wtf? I haven't seen those since 1998

Comment: I believe Google docs created that html that was used. Doesn't work in FF Windows on multiple machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<B>` tag is overriding the `text-decoration`. Just add this:

```
a:hover b{text-decoration:underline;}
```

If there are others you could probably even do:

```
a:hover > *{text-decoration:underline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all a bit over kill I would just use:

a{text-decoration:none;}
a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}

There should be no reason why this doesn't work.

Comment: The example code you pasted is nasty! Try using firebug to check that there are no other styles over riding those set in you style sheet. I wonder if th <b> in the first link is messing it up. Stranger this have happened.

Answer (score 0):

Okay first things first,

Tables for layout - educate yourself please:

http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com

http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3642151/CSS-Layouts-Without-Tables.htm

`<font>` tags were deprecated LONG ago, we now use CSS and `<span>` tags for all our styling needs.

The most likely reason why stuff doesn't work is because your HTML is basically completely wrong, yes it works but it is killing the interwebz - Here is your layout redone with `<div>` tags and CSS - nice and clean and everyone is happy:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q4CqZ/10/)**

Also - validation - It is just a tool, not a standard to aspire to, sure it helps fish out bugs but it could end up causing you hassle trying to be 100% compliant (*Stares at XHTML Strict*) more on that here:

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/general/but-it-doesnt-validate/

Comment: As I said, this code is pre-existing. How do I fix it across 50 pages littered with font tags? Is there an automated tool to do this?

Comment: Why and how are you pulling code from Google docs :O - You just need to do a complete overhaul on your site, If you are going to do something, do it right... right?

Comment: I wasn't the one who did it, I was told that Google docs was used to convert a lot of content from Word to "clean" html. But looks like Google docs doesn't use clean HTML. Why is Google using deprecated tags and why do people use autoconversion tools? Geez. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967191/why-would-google-use-a-font-tag

Comment: Oh god.. designed in Word? You have a long hard road ahead of you my friend, The best way to do it is do it by hand, you could come up with a regex style replacement script to replace the `<font>` with `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

I see the :hover underline on both links in FF 3.6/Mac, even when they are visited links.

As Alex Thomas pointed out, your CSS can be more concise--consider that all the link states are the same color, and only the :hover state differs by having an underline.

Even though the crummy HTML from Google Docs has the color stated on those `font` tags (retro, eh?), duplicate the color rule in your CSS so the :hover underline appears in the correct color:

```
a {
color: #b80000;
text-decoration:none;
} 
a:hover{ text-decoration:underline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with the `text-decoration: underline;` CSS statement.  Firefox ignores this in version 3.6.  I know by version 7.0 it works just fine, but I don't know when it was actually fixed.

What version of Firefox are you working with?